# Lazy Eager Loading for third level relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, lazy-loading, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

UserModel has many lead and each lead can have one propertyLead and each propertyLead can have many attachments.
Each model is listed below,

UserModel:

```
  public function leads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Leads', 'fk_user_id');
}
```

LeadsModel:

```
    public function propertyLead()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\PropertyLead', 'fk_lead_id');
}
```

PropertyLeadModel:

```
    public function attachments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Attachments', 'fk_property_lead_id');
}
```

Now, I am using the **Lazy Eager Loading** of laravel to readData from dataBase, so far I am able to reach to PropertyLeadModel but I am not able to understand how to reach to attachment relation in the PropertyLeadModel,

```
$leads = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->leads->load('propertyLead');
```

so user gives me leads and leads gives me propertyLead but not able to understand how to reach more down to **Attachments** in the propertyLeadModel.

Please, help me to understand.
Thank you.

Comment: you would have to iterate them to get their attachments

Comment: hasmanythough https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: I will check. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load nested relationships using "dot" notation.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->load('leads.propertyLead.attachments');

// see all relationships loaded
dd($user);
```

Since leads and attachments are "many" relationships, they will be Collections you have to iterate through to access any particular instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, not tested

```
$leads = Auth::user()->leads->load('propertyLead', 'propertyLead.attachments');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
User::with('leads.propertyLead.attachments')->where('id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
```